# how to replace substring into lowercase for global search

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use "s/substring/replacement/"replace a substring into all lowercase letters that allow for global search and for case insensitive search.

Reading the file:

```
while(<>){
  print $_/XXX/book/i;  #this line prints the default variable $_
}
```

The sample input:

```
I have a BOOK to read.
I like BoOk to read.
```

The sample output:

```
I have a book to read.
I like book to read.
```

I'm not certain the way using "$_" is right or wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `while(<>) {...}` loop, the topic variable `$_` contains the current line. The substitution operator `s///` uses this variable by default if you do not specify a string to operate on. Try the following code:

```
my $str = 'book';
while(<>){
    s/(\Q$str\E)/lc $1/gei;
    print;
}
```

- Note: If you don't want to replace a substring `book` inside another word, you can add word boundaries `\b` to the regex:

  ```
  s/\b(\Q$str\E)\b/lc $1/gei;
  ```
- Note: It is safer to use the double brackets `<<>>` instead of `<>`, see [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop) for more details.

Comment: thanks! itis very helpful, But I have some questions: is it necessary to use \Q \E in this case? what is the $1 meaning? I didn't find the reference about "gei", does it work the same as 'i'?

Comment: The `\Q` and `\E` are used to escape possible meta characters in `$str`, see [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) for more information. The capture variable `$1` is used together with the grouping meta characters `(` and `)` to extract the matched substring, see [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching) for more information. The `g` modifier does global substitution, meaning that all occurences (not only a single) of the string will be replaced on a line.

Comment: ... See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Global-matching) for more information on the `g` modifier